# adapting an old-fashioned cast of a std::streampos to be g++ 4.4 compatible

Tags: c++, casting, g++, stream

Good afternoon,

I'm attempting to get some old-fashioned code to function in g++ 4.4.  My understanding is the code compiled fine in g++ 4.0, but g++ has become more strict between 4.0 and 4.4. This code in particular causes the compiler to stop and complain:

```
sprintf(s,"%.7d",(long)tellp());
```

tellp() is a std::streampos object. The above call to sprintf occurs inside a derived class from a std::fstream class.

The code *intends* to cast data that indicates the position in an fstream object to a numerical type, so that it can be passed to a 2nd running program (via a file) so that the 2nd program can quickly look-up some data in a file.

Is there a simple way to rescue this, with a cast g++ would be happy with?

The error message:

```
error: format ‘%.7d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘std::streamoff’
```

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be a portable way to do this, since std::fpos is basically implementation defined.  That said, gcc doesn't treat a std::streampos as much of anything like a number.  On the other hand, you can convert it into a std::streamoff, which is architecture dependent for its actual type, but is some manner of typedef to `long` or `long long` or whatever.  Subtract the desired offset from the first position of the stream and it returns `std::streamoff` which can be trivially converted to long.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the problem that %d requires an int and you are casting to a long?

Should this be "%.7ld"?